How I can show a topological space is countably compact with some given condition
Let X be a Hausdorff space. If, of any two disjoint closed sets, at least
one is compact, or even countably compact, then X is countably compact.

I know that countably compactness <=> every collection of closed set with fip has countable intersection.
Here I started with contradiction method but fails to apply the given condition
Any suggestions 

Countable compactness does not imply that "every collection of closed set with fip has countable intersection". A counterexample is $X=[0,3]$, $F_1=[0,2],F_2=[1,3]$.

Presumably, you meant “every countable collection of closed sets with fip has nonempty intersection”.

Note that this is an exercise from "Rings of Continuous Functions"

@AnneBauval I am sorry for my typing error

@DavidGao you are wright

Then please edit your post to fix it.

Here is a different characterization of countable compactness: For a $T_1$ space $X$, $X$ is countably compact iff there is no infinite closed discrete subset of $X$.
Proof: Assume $X$ is countably compact and $K \subset X$ is closed discrete. Then $K$, being a closed subset of a countably compact space, is countably compact as well. But an infinite discrete space cannot be countably compact, so $K$ must be finite.
Now, assume no infinite closed discrete subset of $X$ exists. Assume to the contrary that $X$ is not countably compact. Then there exists a countable open cover of $X$ that admits no finite subcover. By taking finite unions, we see that there exists a strictly increasing sequence $\{O_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ of open sets whose union is $X$. For any $n$, pick $x_n \in O_{n+1}\setminus O_n$. Let $K = \{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$. $K$ is, of course, infinite. It is discrete since $\{x_n\} = (O_{n+1} \setminus \{x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1}\}) \cap K$. It is closed since,
$$X \setminus K = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (O_n \setminus \{x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1}\})$$
so $X \setminus K$ is open and thus $K$ is closed. But then $K$ is an infinite closed discrete subset of $X$, contradicting our assumption. $\square$
This now easily implies the result you asked for: Assume, for any two disjoint closed subsets of $X$, at least one is countably compact. Assume to the contrary that $X$ is not countably compact. Then by above, there exists $K \subset X$ infinite, closed, and discrete. We may write $K = K_1 \cup K_2$ where $K_1$, $K_2$ are infinite disjoint. Any subset of a closed discrete subset is closed discrete itself, so $K_1$ and $K_2$ are closed discrete. By assumption, at least one of them is countably compact. But both are infinite discrete sets, so neither can be countably compact, a contradiction.

Let me observe that, even if the assumption is for any two disjoint closed sets, one of them is compact, this is not enough to imply $X$ is compact. A counterexample is $X=\omega_1$. If $K_1,K_2$ are disjoint closed, then one of them has to be bounded, say $K_1$. (See here for a proof of the fact that the intersection of two closed unbounded subsets is unbounded, so in particular nonempty.) But then $K_1$ is countable. It is also a closed subset of the countably compact $X$, so $K_1$ is compact. However, $X$ is not compact.

(In fact, any limit ordinal $\kappa$ with uncountable cofinality works, not just $\omega_1$.)
